# Why aren't my hyperlinks changing colors or underlining?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Why aren't my hyperlinks changing colors or underlining?  I have in my CSS in a standard VS 2010 site:

```
a:link, a:visited
{
color: #034af3;
outline: none;
}

a:hover
{
color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}

a:active
{
color: #034af3;
outline: none;
}

p
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
line-height: 1.6em;
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Am I in the wrong spot?  Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio site that comes with the software ....

Comment: Can you post the full code for the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it set to not display any text-decoration on hover.

With Hover Decoration:
http://jsfiddle.net/KbZNb/

Without Hover Decoration:
http://jsfiddle.net/KbZNb/1/

It looks like it is changing color, but only slightly due to the color similarities of `#1d60ff` and `#034af3`

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, Brad .... I think I'll figure it out; i appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: I hada fccs in my site master, not css ..  ugh ... I feel stupid.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is rule out that there are no other style rules being applied later that override yours, or none earlier that are more specific (or use `!important`) which will not be overridden by your styles.

Also make sure your CSS is in the right place within the HTML.

Make sure there are no other elements, such as a `span`, within the link that might have styles applied to them which are overriding the `a` styles.

There are a multitude of other debugging steps to take, but I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: thanks ... my css is in my /styles/ folder .... but i'll recheck that.  thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

The colors are nearly the same that's why you didn't see the changes. Change the a:hover to #ff0000 and see the outcome

```
a:hover {color:#ff0000}
```

Comment: #1d60ff and #034af3 are the same color

Comment: Good point.  He should still see the underline disappear, though.

Comment: Thanks Tumise .... i appreciate your help .... i've checked on other puters, and the underline doesn't disappear .... but thanks for your help!